# In speed chess (especially bullet), are dirty tactics tolerated more?

Tags: etiquette, bullet-chess

In bullet chess, well, it's frantic. And sometimes I find myself making dubious checks just to gain time. Or funny gambits. But it feels unbefitting of the royal game.

Is bullet chess bad for the overall chess community's reputation?

Comment: When people are playing a 1-minute game of "chess," I'd think it should be expected that the clock will be the single most important piece in the game (much more so than any piece that's on the board). So it seems to me that strategies focused on the clock would be the norm.

Comment: @EdDean - That's a very good point, thanks!

Comment: Never forget the power of the "move the piece closest to the clock" rule when you have less than 20 seconds left.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bullet chess and speed chess are different sorts of games; they favor those with more talent.  The clock is an integral part of the game.  Use it.  Embrace it.

And no, it isn't any worse for the community than bughouse or any other insane variant.

Answer (score 7):

In my opinion chess and bullet chess are a kind of sport or competition. Everything what happens on the board is legitimate, if it is according to the rules. There is no such thing as an evil or devious move. You may play risky, repeat moves or do moves for "psychological" reasons. If the opponent thinks there is something wrong with that she or he needs to show it by playing better.

Sometimes player continue playing a drawn position, because their opponent runs out of time and they hope that the opponent will blunder. That is fine, since time is part of the game. Anand won a game against Gelfand in this way in last world championship